# Getting my modal to have the correct product with livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm learning to use livewire with laravel. The problem I'm having is that when I click on my delete button
my modal that pops up is not getting the product that I selected instead I get the last product in my table.

Here is my Products.php

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Products\Http\Livewire;

use Modules\Products\Models\Product;
use Livewire\Component;

class Products extends Component
{
    public $modal = false;

    protected $listeners = [
        'productDeleted' => 'deleteModal',
        'close' => 'close',
        'confirmDelete' => 'delete'
    ];

    public function render()
    {
        return view('products::livewire.products', [
            'products' => Product::all()
        ]);
    }

    public function deleteModal($id)
    {
        $this->modal = true;
    }

    public function close()
    {
        $this->modal = false;
    }
}
```

This is my products.blade.php

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <button wire:click="$emit('productDeleted', {{ $product->id }})" class="bg-red-400 hover:bg-red-300 text-red-800 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded inline-flex items-center">Delete</button>
    @if($modal)
        @include('products::livewire.deleteProductModal', ['product' => $product])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

My deleteProductModal.blade.php

```
{{ $product->title}}
```

Comment: `deleteModal($id)` here `$id` your not getting ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul - even if I find the product, I'm not sure how to pass it to the modal so that I can delete the correct product

Comment: why you need to pass in model when you have component  and event

Comment: I'm using the modal to confirm that the user wants to delete the product, but the problem I'm having is that it isn't getting the correct product to delete

Comment: make new property `public $isConfrm = false;` and based on show model in onClick

Comment: Isn't that what I'm doing with `public $modal = false;`

Answer (score 0):

for me i used event and it works perfectly.

```
//component
protected $listeners = ['ProductId'];
    public $productId;

    public function ProductId($id)
    {
        $this->productId= $id;
        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('ProductId');
    }
```

```
//blade

<button type="button" wire:click="$emit('ProductId',{{ $product->id}})" >show modal </button>

// you can put $key where you want
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ $key }}</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('ProductId', event => {
    $("#exampleModal").modal('show');
  })
</script>
```

i hope it will helpful for your work :)